# Maximum integer range of Number

Tags: actionscript-3

We are doing some maths with large integers in Actionscript 3. Because there is no `long` type, we are using `Number`.

What's the range of consecutive integers (positive to negative) a `Number` can accurately represent before it starts to veer into floating point errors?

Comment: The Number data type can use up to 53 bits to represent integer values http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActionScript® 3.0 Reference for the Adobe® Flash® Platform states that the `Number` data type adheres to the double-precision IEEE-754 standard. In IEEE-754 double-precision, there are 64 bits in use (1 for sign bit, 11 bits for exponent and 52 bits for fraction).

Therefor maximum integer range should be approximately ±1.7976931348623157×(10^308)

See Also `MAX_VALUE` and `MIN_VALUE` in `Number` class.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question, when not using a floating point representation the integer range is up to 2<sup>53</sup>-1 (the sign is in a different bit). **+/- 9007199254740991**

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)